# Firebase Security Rules - using get in a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to setup security rules for my firestore instance, I have three basic requirements:

1. User must be authenticated to read
2. Owners of documents are the only
   ones who can write to them (use a field called owner on document to
   verify)
3. Any admin user can also write to any document

The code below achieves all of this (excluded the check for ownership) but the get function to determine the users role only works when specified on the same row as the if condition. In the code below the update and delete works for the admin but not the create.

Can anyone please tell why the isAdmin() function does not evaluate to the same result?

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Only 'owners' of data can make changes to data
    match /posts/{post} {    
      allow read: if isAuthenticated();
      allow create: if isAuthenticated() && isAdmin();
      allow update, delete: if isAuthenticated() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 1;      
    }
  } 

  /// FUNCTIONS ///
  function isAuthenticated() {
     return request.auth.uid != null;
  }

  // function requestIsOwner() {
  //   return request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
  // }

  // function resourceIsOwner() {
  //   return resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
  // }

  function isAdmin() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work in the console simulator, or when these rules are actually deployed?  The console simulator is known to be incorrect in some cases.

Comment: For me it we as during deployment I seen this type of discrepancy with the console which doesn't help when you're trying to figure out what works

Comment: can get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data be saved into a var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the **database** variable as argument in your function like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Only 'owners' of data can make changes to data
    match /posts/{post} {    
      allow read: if isAuthenticated();
      allow create: if isAuthenticated() && isAdmin(database);
      allow update, delete: if isAuthenticated() && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 1;      
    }
  } 

  /// FUNCTIONS ///
  function isAuthenticated() {
     return request.auth.uid != null;
  }

  // function requestIsOwner() {
  //   return request.resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
  // }

  // function resourceIsOwner() {
  //   return resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
  // }

  function isAdmin(database) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see the function is actually out of scope of the match block so it can't resolve the $database variable

Comment: can get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data be saved into a var?